# What is the intention of Sqoop options? -single --double munus difference?

Tags: hadoop, hive, sqoop

In the given example: username followed by one - where as --connect and --table other commands followed by double -- what is the intention of such Sqoop options? Where should I use single and where double?

> sqoop-import  --connect jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/db1 -username
>   root -password password --table tableName  --hive-table tableName
>   --create-hive-table --hive-import --hive-home path/to/hive_home

1. List item

Answer (score 2):

Generic Hadoop arguments are preceded by a single dash character (`-`), whereas sqoop arguments start with two dashes (`--`), unless they are single character arguments such as `-P`.
Generic hadoop command-line arguments supported are: 
`-conf <configuration file>`     specify an application configuration file
`-D <property=value>`            use value for given property
`-fs <local|namenode:port>`      specify a namenode
`-jt <local|jobtracker:port>`    specify a job tracker
`-files <comma separated list of files>`    specify comma separated files to be copied to the map reduce cluster
`-libjars <comma separated list of jars>`    specify comma separated jar files to include in the classpath.
`-archives <comma separated list of archives>`    specify comma separated archives to be unarchived on the compute machines.

**FYI:** You must supply the generic hadoop arguments `-conf`, `-D`, and so on after the tool name but before any tool-specific arguments (such as `--connect`).